# Product editing page (admin panel ) Not working HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: magento-1.9, product, admin-panel

hey guys i was doing import export process for product. now when i go to backend of my old store for product customization . Page is not opening & it shows error . Anyone know how to deal with it Urgent.
This page isn’t Working
rdskingdom.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: To check what the actual error is, uncomment `display_errors` in your `Magento_core_folder/app/bootstrap.php` file. Then it could be resolved when you know the reason.

Comment: it showing 500 error . any other way ?\

Comment: If you uncomment it correctly, it should show the error, For 500 errors, you need to know the reason to cope with them.

Comment: there is no word "display errors" in app/bootstrap.php

Comment: `#ini_set('display_errors', 1);` this is the exact line. Remove `#` from beginning.

Comment: if (function_exists('libxml_disable_entity_loader')) {
    libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);
}
i have only that code in bootstrap.php

Comment: Is there any other way to check error ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115985/discussion-between-abdul-samad-abbasi-and-syze-developer).

Comment: 2020-11-07T10:36:31+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found  in /home2/fillcraf/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2020-11-07T10:36:31+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): /*   in /home2/fillcraf/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2020-11-07T10:36:31+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^  in /home2/fillcraf/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510